# iOS 'startTunnelWithOptions:completionHandler:' method of 'PacketTunnelProvider' not be called

Tags: ios

When run this code  :`[_manager.connection startVPNTunnelWithOptions:nil    andReturnError:&startError]`.

Method `startTunnelWithOptions:completionHandler:` of `PacketTunnelProvider`not be called.

Why is this method not invoked or need other configuration?

thank you.